# KDE not working after installing on !(k)Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: kde, 16.10, plasma

I started liking KDE a few days ago, when I installed it on an Arch Linux VM. So I tried to install it on my Ubutnu 16.10, using the kubuntu-desktop package. I logged out, switched to KDE Plasma, and logged in. There was the loading screen, it dissappeared and i was presented with a blank black screen. Or not so blank - there was the cursor, it registered both my screens - I could move my  cursor across both screens. Also there are a few windows, that normally show up (in Unity), when I login. I can move these windows, resize them, get the right-click menu, etc. But nothing else.

I searched all over the internet, asked friends and tried everything I knew that could help. I've got no idea what to do.

**EDIT #1:**
Tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`, did nothing.

Also, when I log back in Unity, after I tried to run Plasma, apport throws some errors at me, i think it is plasmashell, compiz and kappmanager, but I am not sure, and I think the errors are slightly different each time.
Wierd.

Comment: switch back to Unity and fully update your system.

Comment: @CelticWarrior which command? apt upgrade?

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: @CelticWarrior Yup, nothing happened.  Also, when I log back in Unity, apport throws some errors at me, usually it is plasmashell, compiz and kappmanager, but I don't remember it exactly.